# wxPython, OpenGL.GLU import ordering matters?

Tags: opengl, wxpython, pyopengl

I'm in the following situation. I have a module with a GLCanvas, a wx.Panel that contains the canvas and some buttons and a frame that displays them. Now my imports are as follow:

from OpenGL.GLU import gluPerspective
   from OpenGL.GLUT import glutSolidSphere

```
from OpenGL.GL import GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT, GL_LEQUAL, GL_DEPTH_TEST, GL_SMOOTH, GL_PROJECTION
from OpenGL.GL import GL_LIGHTING, GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, GL_AMBIENT, GL_DIFFUSE, GL_SPECULAR, GL_LIGHT_MODEL_TWO_SIDE
from OpenGL.GL import GL_MODELVIEW,GL_TRIANGLES,GL_POINTS,GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,GL_UNSIGNED_INT,GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT,GL_NICEST
from OpenGL.GL import glClear, glLoadIdentity, glTranslatef, glTranslate, glRotatef, glRotate, glColor4f, glClearColor, glClearDepth, glDepthFunc, glEnable
from OpenGL.GL import glViewport, glShadeModel, glMatrixMode, glDrawElements, glHint, glLightfv , glLightModeli
from wx.glcanvas import GLCanvas
import wx
```

This works fine. However if I try to move the import wx.glcanvas and import wx before the imports from GLU and GLUT python crashes with a "Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)". Since this frame won't be my starting frame I have to call import wx before in other modules and when I reach this it will just crash. Any suggestions ?

**Edit**

So to better explain the problem. I have module 1 with my GLCanvas, GLPanel and MainWindow:

```
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from wx.glcanvas import GLCanvas
import wx

class myGLCanvas(GLCanvas):
---------some initialisations and stuff-------
#Actual draw
def OnDraw(self):
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()                    
    glTranslatef(0.0, -5.0, -250.0)
    glTranslate(0.0, 0.0, -self.distance)
    glRotate(self.alpha, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    glRotate(self.beta, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
    for b in self.dataBuffers:  
        b.bindAll()
        glDrawElements(self.glDisplayType, b.size, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0)
        b.unbind() 
    self.SwapBuffers()
-------------------more code------------------
================End of class GLCanvas=======================

class GLPanel(wx.Panel):
def __init__(self, parent, canvas, *args, **kwargs):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
    self.canvas = canvas

    self.button1 = wx.Button(self, label="POINTS")
    self.button2 = wx.Button(self, label="TRIANGLES")

    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.setPoints, self.button1)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.setTriangles, self.button2)

    self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    self.sizer.Add(self.button1, flag=wx.BOTTOM, border=5)
    self.sizer.Add(self.button2, flag=wx.BOTTOM, border=5)


    self.border = wx.BoxSizer()
    self.border.Add(self.sizer, flag=wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, border=5)

    self.SetSizerAndFit(self.border)

def setPoints(self, evt):
    self.canvas.setDisplayType(GL_POINTS)
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def setTriangles(self, evt):
    self.canvas.setDisplayType(GL_TRIANGLES)
 ======================End of GLPanel========================= 
class MainWin(wx.Frame):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, title='OpenGL', *args, **kwargs)

    self.canvas = myGLCanvas(self, size=(640, 480))
    self.panel = GLPanel(self, canvas=self.canvas)

    self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
    self.sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.EXPAND)
    self.sizer.Add(self.panel, 0, wx.EXPAND)
    self.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer)

    self.Show()
```

Ok so now if I go ahead and:

```
 app = wx.PySimpleApp(0)
 wx.InitAllImageHandlers() 
 main_win = MainWin(None)
 main_win.Show()
 app.MainLoop()
```

If I do this from the same module or from a module that does not use any import wx before, it works. But my application has a login screen, configuration screen etc that all use wx. So now at the point from my code that I want to create a MainWin(), I get the crash I mentioned before.

Basically what I'm saying is I have to create a GLPanel and myGLCanvas from:

```
import wx

class someOtherScreen(wx.Frame)
--------------code code-------------
canvas = myGLCanvas
```

So now the wx comes before the OpenGL imports and python just crashes.

Comment: This is hard to know as a new user, but when you want to add new information to your question you should do that by editing it (there is an edit link at the very bottom of your question), rather than posting it in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am doing this:

```
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from wx.glcanvas import GLCanvas
import wx
```

This should work fine for any application.

Comment: This works fine if this is the starting module. But say I have my GLModule in which I have the import like you said. But my login frame is using wx, so I have to import wx there. Now if I try to do something like    main_win = GLWindow(None)
app.SetTopWindow(main_win)
app.MainLoop() it still crashes

Comment: This works just like my solution. Meaning if I try something like:

Comment: Please add minimal example in your question (probably split into two files), which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Fixed it eventually. It was a cumulation of some bad indices by me and some buggy pyopengl VBO's. Thanks for the input.